# Backbone returning length of 0

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm fairly new to backbone and I'm trying to build a simple app. This is what I have so far

```
var Election = Backbone.Model.extend();

var Elections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
   model: Election,
   url: '/assets/data.json',

   initialize: function() {
       console.log('init col');
       this.render();
       return this;
   },

   render: function() {
        console.log('rendering the collection');
        return this;
   },

// return this

});

  var router = Backbone.Router.extend({
   routes: {
       '': 'root'
   },

   root: function(){
       var collection = new Elections();
       collection.fetch();
       console.log(collection.length); //returns 0
   }
});
var r = new router();

Backbone.history.start();
```

The log is this

```
> init col
> rendering the collection
> 0
```

But when I create a new collection manually in the console, it shows the right length and everything, I assume that for some reason the router call is happening too early, not sure though. This is a sample of `data.json`

```
[
    {
        "year": 1868,
        ...
    },
    {
        "year": 1872,
        ...
    },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) performs an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request, so you should pass [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) a success callback:

```
collection.fetch({
   success: function(){
       console.log(collection.length);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

expanding on CD's answer a little bit,

a better approach would be calling `fetch` and then using `listenTo` to call the `render` method on change

in your initialize method do this

```
_.bindAll(this, 'render');
this.listenTo(this, 'change', this.render);
```

and you can have the fetch outside if you wish

collection.fetch()

and it will automatically update on change

Comment: can you explain why this would be better? not quite sure. Thanks :)

Comment: its just the backbone way vs jquery way of doing it..
much cleaner to look at too I think and thats how its done in production

Comment: I'm trying to do what you suggested but I can't get it to work. [fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/QJJN9/3/)

Comment: Double post...for some reason it thinks that the view does not have the listenTo method. `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listenTo'`

Comment: make sure you have the latest backbone (1.9 <  ). people were using `.on` before that but `.listenTo` gives us stop listening functionality as well.